# Floating Action Menu to right

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm using the Clan/ActionFlaotingMenu Library and it works fine until you switch to land scape mode , then half of the buttons don't appear.
is there anyway to open the menu to left or right instead of up and down ?

Comment: You should ask here as well, really https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/issues/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to handle this case was to have a separate layout for the landscape mode , and placing a separate action floating buttons in the layout , and make them hide/show based on the Action menu click

Answer (score 1):

Sister, instead of using 3rd party library you use your own code. And I don't know if you didn't implemented any onTouch event. If you had implemented it then you should be able to reposition the floating menu or layout. 
Here is a **[tutorial](http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/)** about this. In this tutorial they have used **ImageView**. You just replace with your menu layout with the ImageView.

Comment: its time consuming in my case since its one case scenario , but its my last option . was looking for something to flip the FAM or a quick way

Comment: That's your choice. As you are saying - coding of your own is timeconsuming, so I have nothing to say. But you must be seen that a good app always try to use as less extra library as possible. And if you are not willing to code your own then submit a issue to that library's owner.